# Installing pgdb: pg_config tool is not available

Tags: python, postgresql, pygresql, pgdb

So here is my goal: To get a .py file that imports pgdb, to run.

For this, as far as I have understood, I need PygreSql.

I have both postgresql 9.4.4 and python 2.7.9 installed (Postgresql with source code and python with the normal download form the website.). I found the file PyGreSQL.tar (version 4.1.1) and I ran the command `python setup.py build` in the directory of the extracted tar file. I get the message `Exception: pg_config tool is not available.`. What can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The PostgreSQL `bin` directory containing `pg_config` must be on the `PATH`. You installed from source so you shouldn't need to worry about -dev or -devel packages; users who install from packages need to also install the appropriate `devel` package for the PostgreSQL server packages they're using. Is `pg_config` on your `PATH`? If you run `pg_config` what's the output?

Answer (score 12):

Try running this:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-X.X
```

in your case X.X is 9.4